# Formidable multi-file upload - ENOENT, no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multipart, formidable

I know this question has been asked but my mind has been blown by my inability to get this working. I am trying to upload multiple images to my server with the following code:

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');
```

...

```
router.post('/add_images/:showcase_id', function(req, res){
    if(!admin(req, res)) return;
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
    files = [];


    form.uploadDir = global.__project_dirname+"/tmp";
    form.on('file', function(field, file) {
        console.log(file);

        file.image_id = global.s4()+global.s4();
        file.endPath = "/img/"+file.image_id+"."+file.type.replace("image/","");
        files.push({field:field, file:file});
    });
    form.on('end', function() {
        console.log('done');
        console.log(files);
        db.get("SOME SQL", function(err, image_number){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            var db_index = 0;
            if(image_number) db_index = image_number.image_order;
            files.forEach(function(file, index){
                try{
                    //this line opens the image in my computer (testing)
                    require("sys").exec("display " + file.file.path);
                    console.log(file.file.path);
                    fs.renameSync(file.file.path, file.file.endPath);
                }catch (e){
                    console.log(e);
                }
                db.run( "SOME MORE SQL"')", function(err){
                    if(index == files.length)
                        res.redirect("/admin/gallery"+req.params.showcase_id);
                });
            });
        });
    });
    form.parse(req);
});
```

The line that opens the image via system calls works just fine, however I continue to get:
`Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/[username]/[project name]/tmp/285ef5276581cb3b8ea950a043c6ed51'`
by the rename statement.

the value of file.file.path is:
`/home/[username]/[project name]/tmp/285ef5276581cb3b8ea950a043c6ed51`

I am so confused and have tried everything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the question about why you are getting `ENOENT`, or why the path isn't some other value. Does the directory it is complaining about exist?

Comment: The question is about why I am getting `ENOENT`. The directory does exist. I know this because without the `try/catch` the server will crash and because this happens before formidable cleans up the upload directory, the files will still be there.

Comment: Is there any stack trace for the error? Just the error message isn't much to work from.

Comment: Have you tried closing everything but the terminal?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm at work so I cant produce the stack trace at this moment.

Comment: @Vinz243 what do you mean? I have sublime, terminal and browser open.

Comment: Close sublime. I had issue with Atom watching files in a dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you get this error because the target path does not exist or you don't have write permissions.

The error you get is misleading due to a bug in nodejs, see:

- https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5287
- https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/685

Consider adding:

```
console.log(file.file.endPath);
```

before the `fs.renameSync` call and check if the target path exist and is writable by your application

Answer (score -1):

You stated form. Therefore note that Formidable doesn't work out of the box with just NodeJS. Unless you were to use something like the prompt module for input. If you are using HTML, you'll need something like Angular, React or Browserify to be able to give it access to your interface.